# Shravan's death

Tags: ramayana

Why did Shravan face such a bad death? If he was so good to his parents, and overall as a son and a person, then why did he go through such pain?
Did his previous janmas’ (births’) karma lead him to this situation?

Comment: Maybe he was some sort of collateral damage or a way to end up his parent's sufferings because they died right after they came to know about his death.

Comment: It is incorrect to assume manner of death is some kind of karma phal. Death is death, in whichever form it comes. What bad did Bhishma did to stay pierced with thousands of arrows for many months out of his own wish? Think.

Answer (score 2):

There is no information about his previous janams.According to the legend in Ramayana, while hunting in the forest of Ayodhya, then-Prince Dashratha heard a sound near a lake and unleashed an arrow, hoping to hit an animal. When he crossed the lake to collect his kill, he found that his arrow had fatally struck a teenage boy who was bleeding. The boy was Shravan.No doubt he is a good son to his parents.